# Angular 5 application very slow while typing letters in a textbox in IE11

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-11, angular5, ie11-developer-tools

My application is built on Angular 5 and facing an issue while typing letters in any text box in IE11, in chrome it works fine. It takes at least 2 seconds to type a single letter in the text box. Memory usage is 400mb in the welcome page and it increases if we go to any other component by 100mb.

So in short I need to improve the typing speed in any textbox. Could you suggest a way to fix this issue.

Comment: We are experiencing similar behaviour. Is it Always or after doing something in the UI ? Our seem to be connected to opening and closing material modal dialogs. Are you using the material library ?

Comment: We are using material but not extensively

Comment: @ViktorEriksson does the answer provided below solved your problem too? I am still fighting with the opening and closing material modal dialogs. IE 11 sucks. OR if you have solved it with other way around please suggest.

Answer (score 9):

This issue is solved now, you need to use enableprodmode() in the main.ts file to make the angular app light weighted and also it limits the dual change detection cycle to one.. further you can use ng build --prod to optimize the build package